# "Like" button on my website brings up go-daddy info instead of mine

Tags: facebook-like

I bought the domain name "www.terry4butte.com" from go-daddy.  I then bought webhosting through ipages so I could make my own page.  When I copied the code for the like and send button from the developers page, it shows go-daddy with my website in it.  I looked through the html script for my website and could not find any reference to go-daddy.  How can I get rid of that and put my own website in the posted content?

Comment: been you your page I think its working fine. Is it some kinda publicity trick??

Comment: nah, see my comments below in my answer.  It's a caching issue with Facebook.  It's seeing his old InstantPage website's data because his new og tags are erroring out the linter from picking up the new values.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has a cool debugger for that. Go to:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.terry4butte.com

Then fix the errors and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The owner probably had an Instant Page (I have one on my domain and LOVE it!) and then upgraded to some other hosting plan.

Facebook appears to be still keeping the old Instant Page data as the new OG tags on the new site are broken and cannot be relinted properly.

Get those fixed where the linter can parse it correctly, then all will be well with the world.